# Assign score to table values

Tags: mysql, triggers

Using the following query:

```
SELECT sum(severity) as Score, DATE_FORMAT(LAST_UPDATE,"%Y-%m") as    
score_date 
FROM  missingpatches 
GROUP BY score_date
```

Is there a way within the query to assign a value for each of the numbers in the 'severity' column and then sum these new values?

For example right now I have:

Severity                    Last_Update
1                           5/1/2012
1                           5/1/2012
2                           5/1/2012
2                           5/1/2012
3                           5/1/2012
3                           5/1/2012

And I would like all 1s to have a score of 10, 2's to have a score of 9 and 3s to have a score of 6

Is there a way to do this within the query?  Or is there a way to insert the scores for each severity into the table automatically using a trigger every time new severity numbers are entered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `CASE WHEN THEN`

```
SELECT sum(CASE severity WHEN 1 THEN 10 WHEN 2 THEN 9 WHEN 3 THEN 6 END) as Score, DATE_FORMAT(LAST_UPDATE,"%Y-%m") as    
score_date 
FROM  missingpatches 
GROUP BY score_date
```